# Python - How can I pass multiple arguments using Pool map

Tags: python, multiprocessing

This is a sniplet of my code:

```
data = [currentAccount.login,currentAccount.password,campaign.titlesFile,campaign.licLocFile,campaign.subCity,campaign.bodiesMainFile,campaign.bodiesKeywordsFile,campaign.bodiesIntroFile]
results = multiprocessing.Pool(5).map(partial(self.postAd,data),range(3))
...
def postAd (self,login,password,titlesFile,licLocFile,subCity,bodiesMainFile,bodiesKeywordsFile,bodiesIntroFile):
...
```

(Just so you know what's going on: currentAccount and campaign are classes, those are variables within those classes. Using self b/c this is all being run in a class. I'm trying to run self.postAd 3x passing it all the variables I have in data)

When I run that it says " postAd() missing 6 required positional arguments: 'titlesFile', 'licLocFile', 'subCity', 'bodiesMainFile', 'bodiesKeywordsFile', and 'bodiesIntroFile'"

What am I doing wrong? Why does it only accept 2 variables?

If I cant use Pool map, how should I be doing this?

I also tried this with no success:

```
results = multiprocessing.Pool(5).map(lambda args: self.postAd(currentAccount.login,currentAccount.password,campaign.titlesFile,campaign.licLocFile,campaign.subCity,campaign.bodiesMainFile,campaign.bodiesKeywordsFile,campaign.bodiesIntroFile), range(3))

Error: Can't pickle <function NewPostService.processNewAds.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x0000000002F3CBF8>: attribute lookup <lambda> on functions failed
```

Comment: I also tried this with no success:

results = multiprocessing.Pool(5).map(lambda args: self.postAd(currentAccount.login,currentAccount.password,campaign.titlesFile,campaign.licLocFile,campaign.subCity,campaign.bodiesMainFile,campaign.bodiesKeywordsFile,campaign.bodiesIntroFile), range(3))

Error: Can't pickle <function NewPostService.processNewAds.<locals>.<lambda> at 0x0000000002F3CBF8>: attribute lookup <lambda> on functions failed

Comment: Do you really want all three calls to use *exactly* the same arguments? I'm not sure that works with `map`, since it will always want to be providing an extra argument from the sequence it loops over (the `range` in this case). You can probably make it work by writing an extra function that ignores its last argument (and using `partial(self.postadd, *data)`), but it might be easier to use your own loop creating `Process`es.

Comment: Yes I want it to use the same arguments. I want the same process to happen 3x simultaneously is the reason why.

How would I do this " but it might be easier to use your own loop creating Processes." Can you give me an example based on my code if you'd be so kind

Answer (score 0):

Your first attempt is a misuse of `partial`. `data` is a single argument: it being a list doesn't automatically unpack its contents. `partial` simply takes variable arguments and so you should pass those arguments 'normally', either

```
partial(self.postAd, currentAccount.login,currentAccount.password, ...
```

or

```
partial(self.postAd, *data)
```

The reason it says that `postAd` received two arguments instead of just one (`data`) is that it also implicitly received the `self` argument.

Your second attempt is the right idea and very close, but it so happens that [in older versions of python pickle (which is essential for multiprocessing) can't handle lambdas](http://bugs.python.org/issue19272). Replace the lambda with a named function defined using `def`:

```
def postNow(arg):  # Accepts an argument from map which it ignores
    self.postAd(currentAccount.login, ..., campaign.bodiesIntroFile)
```

Side notes:

It's a bit odd that your argument to the lambda is called `args` when it's just one argument. If your intention is to make it flexible and accept variable arguments, use `lambda *args: ...` or even `lambda *args, **kwargs: ...` to accept keyword arguments. The names are not important, they are just convention. The important part is the `*` and `**`. Note that `partial` has a signature like this, as an example.

I have never seen this issue with the second attempt before. I learnt it by Googling the error message. Always Google things.

Comment: Thanks for the response Alex. I'm still a beginner python programmer so some of this is over my head. I tried doing both options of 1. partial(self.postAd, *data) and 2. multiprocessing.Pool(5).map(partial(self.postAd,currentAccount.login,currentAccount.password,campaign.titlesFile,campaign.licLocFile,campaign.subCity,campaign.bodiesMainFile,campaign.bodiesKeywordsFile,campaign.bodiesIntroFile),range(3)   ----------------- . and got this error for both of them:  Error: postAd() takes 9 positional arguments but 10 were given. I'm not sure where the 10th argument is as I'm only passing 8.

Comment: @DanielRusu it's getting the 8 normal arguments, `self`, and the 10th is the value from `range(3)` passed in by `map`. It wouldn't make much sense to modify `postAd` for this case so actually just forget about trying to use `partial`, it's not intended for this.